# Angular 4: Bar Chart with D3.js not fetching the subscribed data

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, observable

I'm developing a Bar Chart with D3.js and I'm using Observable to fetch the value from API.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataCollectionService
      .getAllCurrencyData()
      .subscribe(
        (currData) => {
          this.currencyData = currData;
        });

    this.initSvg();
    this.initAxis();
    this.drawAxis();
    this.drawBars();
  }

  private initSvg() {
    this.svg = d3.select("svg");
    this.width = +this.svg.attr("width") - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = +this.svg.attr("height") - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.g = this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");
  }

  private initAxis() {
    this.x = d3Scale.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, this.width]).padding(0.1);
    this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().rangeRound([this.height, 0]);
    this.x.domain(this.currencyData.map((d) => d.symbol));
    this.y.domain([0, d3Array.max(this.currencyData, (d) => d.price_usd)]);
  }

  private drawAxis() {
    this.g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(d3Axis.axisBottom(this.x));
    this.g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3Axis.axisLeft(this.y).ticks(5))
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "axis-title")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Dollar Value");
  }

  private drawBars() {
    this.g.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(this.currencyData)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", (d) => this.x(d.symbol) )
      .attr("y", (d) => this.y(d.price_usd) )
      .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", (d) => this.height - this.y(d.price_usd) );
  }
```

Problem I'm facing is,  all the chart methods are getting executed before this.currencyData subscribes to all the values. Hence no chat is getting displayed I put all chart methods inside subscribe but it dint help. I also tried with putting the service call inside constructor but no luck.

Any solution for this issue please?

Comment: When you said `put all chart methods inside subscribe but didn't help` -- what happened? what value is coming back for `currData`?

Comment: @aug currdata is returning the values with little delay

Comment: It should ideally be inside the subscribe method.
But did you console.log in the subscribe...what all values does it return.
whats the initial value.

Comment: @Cyril I did console.log of this.currencyData and its fetching all the objects correctly.

Comment: how many console logs did you get, and what all values did you get?

Comment: The problem I found. In my service, instead of returning res.json() I was returning res.json.  Thank you all for the suggestions